# Task Scheduler always launches applications in background. How to launch in foreground?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, application-launch

It is a problem I encountered in Windows 10 task scheduler.

I created a basic task whose action is start a batch file as follows:

```
start "BitComet" "C:\Program Files\BitComet\BitComet.exe"
start "Bandicam" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bandicam\bdcam.exe" /record
```

When I run the batch file by double clicking it in Windows Explorer, the two GUI applications run in foreground as expected.

If I run it in Task Scheduler by 1) right clicking the task, and 2) left clicking the "Run" menuitem in the popup menu, the two applications are running in the background, which I observe in the Background processes list of Task Manager's Processes tab.

I want to run the two GUI applications in foreground, not in background, because I need to record the screen. I have checked all the options I know in the task properties dialog but found no way to specify running the batch file (in turn the two apps therein) in foreground. I use batch file because this is the only way I can figure out to run two applications at once in a single scheduled task.

Can you please let me know how to have the two GUI applications run in foreground triggered by a scheduled task? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security and privacy matters when a GUI task is scheduled to run. If the screen is currently used by another user B and the scheduled task can only run by user A because the GUI window may contain private information of A, security and privacy is infringed if the task is running in foreground. For this reason, the task must be run in background without displaying any window, even though it is a GUI app.

So, the solution is very simple: make A=B. That is, select "Run only when user is logged on" in the Security options of the General tab in the task's properties dialog. I selected "Run whether user is logged on or not" previously because I'm afraid there is not enough time for the correct user to login so the task may fails to start. Under "Run whether ..." option, the Task Scheduler prevents the window from showing in case the screen is currently used by some other user. I have to say the wording in the UI is very misleading. Anyway, by switching from "Run whether ..." to "Run only when ...", the two GUI applications are run as expected in foreground through the task-scheduled batch file.

Answer (score 0):

These are the rules https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow.

> **The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window.** A
> process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> •The process is the foreground process.
>
> •The process was started by the foreground process.
>
> •The process received the last input event.
>
> •There is no foreground process.
>
> •The process is being debugged.
>
> •The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start
> Screen.
>
> •The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
>
> •The foreground lock time-out has expired (see
> SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
>
> •No menus are active.

**Note:** Task Scheduler is never the foreground process.

---

*Hotkeys are system keys so work all the time. To take the example below, using sendkeys to send Ctrl+N to any application will activate Notepad. This is one way around restrictions on setting the active window.* See *HotkeyToWindow.exe Assigns a hotkey to a window. When pressed will activate that window.* at https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/hotkeytowindowexe-assigns-hotkey-to.html.

See vbscript `sendkeys`.

Comment: Please clarify how your answer is related to my question.

Comment: It answers very specifically why starting it in task scheduler won't make the foreground window. See **Point 2 in above list**.

Comment: "foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true" != "background if one of the following conditions is false".  **See Point 1 in the above list**.

Comment: Task Scheduler is never a foreground process. I gave you a work around.

Comment: I have figured out what the problem is. Your answer is just totally wrong and not to the point; the problem has nothing to do with "set the foreground window". PS, Task Scheduler is obviously a foreground process, unless you're blind. I'll answer my own question.

Comment: A foreground window has user input focus. There can only be one.

Answer (score 0):

Only one application can get the focus.

Try this:

Start Program field: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe`
Argument field: `/c start "BitComet" "C:\Program Files\BitComet\BitComet.exe"`

This will basically open up `cmd.exe` and pass the arguments to it.
The `/c` parameter will run those arguments and then close,
while `start` gives the focus to anything it starts.

Comment: 1) the problem is not about focus, but no windows. 2) I wanna run two GUI applications at once.

Comment: Have you defined the tasks as "Run only when user is logged on" and using your login account?

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler tasks can have more than one Action. Create multiple Actions, one for each of the apps you want to start.